# 'fc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

Even running as an administrator, it seems only to work when I'm in the folder: C:\Windows\System32\

Any advice on how to make it work from anywhere in the C:\ directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PATH statement is fubar.

It should include at least these things assuming windows in in c:\windows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```

Comment: What do you mean by PATH statement is fubar?

Comment: @Matthew Your edit has no value because Windows is not case sensitive, and it makes absolutely no difference to the line by changing the case of words.  It might be better to edit actual flaws, and help format code where the OP has trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set/update your path with this command:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;c:\windows\system32"
```

Or add the `/M` if you run an elevated prompt to set it systemwide for all users

To see the effect of this change you have start a new command prompt.

If you only want to update the path in your current command prompt do:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\windows\system32
```

To examine your current PATH environment var type

```
SET PATH
```

at the command prompt. To spare 4 keystrokes you can also leave out `SET`